# How to change or add a header to the "Print PDF Report" action

Tags: pdf, templates, header-footer

I would like to add a header of my logo to "Print PDF Report" action when a search or report is generated. Is it something easily achievable? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the "Title and Format" tab on the report, you can edit the html for the Header and Footer. The default footer has an image in the footer. Its in the documentation at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/reporting/set-up/